# How can i use useReducer to assign initial state after calling custom Datafetch hook? I keep getting null

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I created a custom datafetch hook but when i use the reducer function to set it as initial state it says its null.

Component where i call the custom Hook.

```
const collection = 'items'
const whereClause = { array: "lists", compare: 'array-contains', value: 'Pantry' }
const res = useDataFetchWhere(collection, whereClause)
const data = res.response
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, data)
```

When I console.log(state) I get null.

My custom data fetch hook

```
const useDataFetchWhere = (collection, whereClause) => {

    const [response, setResponse] = useState(null)
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)


    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            setIsLoading(true)
            setError(false)
            try {
                await db.collection(collection).where(whereClause.array, whereClause.compare, whereClause.value).get()
                    .then(data => {
                        setResponse(data.docs.map(doc => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })))
                        setIsLoading(false)
                        console.log('hello where')
                    })

            } catch (error) {
                setError(error)
            }
        }
        fetchData()
        return function cleanup() {
            console.log('cleaned up check')
        };
    }, [])

    return { response, error, isLoading }
}
```

Is there anything i need to do or call in a different way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `useDataFetchWhere` does not immediately return the result of the data fetching, but only after a while the request is done and then the `setResponse` will set the actual data. So you cannot set the response as initial state for the `useReducer` call.

You need to wait until the request is done before using it's result. You could create an action (e.g. `SET_DATA`) for the reducer that sets the result once it's there.

You already have the `isLoading` flag available:

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, null);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!isLoading) {
    const data = res.response;
    dispatch({type: 'SET_DATA', data});
  }
}, [isLoading]);
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to do the if function without a useEffect and it went into like an infinite loop. Works great.